# botocore.response.StreamingBody gives JSONDecodeError

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, boto, botocore

I am trying to load a payload returned by a lambda invocation but getting `JSONDecodeError`
Below is my lambda code.

```
from datetime import datetime
metadata={}
metadata["execution_info"] = {
            "aws_lambda_request_id": "test",
            "aws_lambda_instance_id": "test",
            "started_timestamp": datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
            }
metadata["execution_info"]["completed_timestamp"] = datetime.utcnow().isoformat()
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    return {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": json.dumps({
        "body": metadata
    })
}
```

Then in my calling function when I try to load the reponse, like below

```
response=lambda_mock.invoke(
    FunctionName='test-lambda',
    InvocationType='RequestResponse'
)
response=json.load(response['Payload'])
```

It throws

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
E           json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py:355: JSONDecodeError
```

Tried this as well- `response=json.loads(response['Payload'].read().decode("utf-8"))` but still same error.

What is going wrong here ?

Update 1-

print(response['Payload']) gives <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7f1907af1400>

**Root Cause**

I think I have found the issue. Looks like the mock lambda is returning bad data. It's returning the expected response + lambda logs (start request/end request details). It's somehow combining them both and returning them as one unit. I have no clue why is this happening.

`print(response['Payload'].read())` generates below responses in my local and container. It's strange that same code produces two different output.

### local

```
{'statusCode': 200, 'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 'body': '{"body": {"execution_info": {"aws_lambda_request_id": "test", "aws_lambda_instance_id": "test", "started_timestamp": "some-time", "completed_timestamp": "some-time"}}}'}
```

### container

```
b'\x1b[32mSTART RequestId: 14b675fe-bea2-1072-ceb7-53f0a72ac92c Version: 1\x1b[0m\n\x1b[32mEND RequestId: 14b675fe-bea2-1072-ceb7-53f0a72ac92c\x1b[0m\n\x1b[32mREPORT RequestId: 14b675fe-bea2-1072-ceb7-53f0a72ac92c\tInit Duration: 432.19 ms\tDuration: 3.07 ms\tBilled Duration: 4 ms\tMemory Size: 1000 MB\tMax Memory Used: 23 MB\t\x1b[0m\n\n{"statusCode":200,"headers":{"Content-Type":"application/json"},"body":"{\\"body\\": {\\"execution_info\\": {\\"aws_lambda_request_id\\": \\"test\\", \\"aws_lambda_instance_id\\": \\"test\\", \\"started_timestamp\\": \\"some-time\\", \\"completed_timestamp\\": \\"some-time\\"}}}"}'
```

**Phew !**
Moto 1.3.14 has this bug. Degraded moto version on my local and now I am getting the same error.

Comment: what does print(response['Payload']) output?

Comment: It prints this <botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7f1907af1400>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to Moto version.
I was using 1.3.14 in my build pipeline and latest version on my local.
The old version is having this bug where it returns incorrect response from your mocked lambda.
Once I upgraded the moto version in my build pipeline, it all worked fine.

You might see `docker not found` once you upgrade moto version. To fix that, include `moto[all]==2.0.5` in requirements.txt

Refer this thread for more details : [moto- docker not found issue](https://github.com/spulec/moto/issues/3297)